# Setting environment variables from Gradle

Tags: ant, environment-variables, gradle

I need to execute from Gradle an Ant script which relies on environment variables. 
Ant uses `<property environment="env"/>` for it.

I tried to do `env.foo="bar"` in Gradle, but it throws a Groovy exception.

What is the proper way to pass environment variables from Gradle to Ant?

Comment: Did you try to use the Ant build script via `ant.importBuild 'build.xml'`?

Comment: @Benjamin That's what I am trying to accomplish. Unfortunately the legacy Ant script relies on several environment variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to set environment variables from Gradle or JVM in general, but it is possible to trick Ant like this:

```
ant.project.properties['env.foo'] = 'bar'
```

Comment: I get an error: `Could not find property '' on task '`

Answer (score 13):

From the [gradle 2.0 docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html), i see something like this is possible

```
test {
  environment "LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "lib"
}
```

Or in this case could use this

```
systemProperty "java.library.path", "lib"
```

Comment: I wish I had Gradle 2.0 two years ago :)

Comment: I tried this in my build.gradle file (with another variable name). Then I check the system variable in my test like this: `assertTrue(System.getenv().containsKey("SOME_TEST_VAR"));` This gives an assertion error. So, it looks like the environment variable is not set.

Comment: I get an error `Could not find method systemProperty() for arguments`

Answer (score 2):

Accepted solution from @Sergey:

```
ant.project.properties['env.foo'] = 'bar'
```

**Does not work** for me on `gradle` 2.9 and `ant` 1.9.7.
That did not thrown any error, but do nothing. Indeed if you are look at code it [implemented as](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ant/ant/1.9.6/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.java?av=f#652):

```
public Hashtable<String, Object> getProperties() {
    return PropertyHelper.getPropertyHelper(this).getProperties();
}
```

where [org.apache.tools.ant.PropertyHelper#getProperties is](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ant/ant/1.9.6/org/apache/tools/ant/PropertyHelper.java#PropertyHelper.getProperties%28%29):

```
public Hashtable<String, Object> getProperties() {
    //avoid concurrent modification:
    synchronized (properties) {
        return new Hashtable<String, Object>(properties);
    }
}
```

So it make explicit copy and it can't work.

**The way do it correctly** in `gradle` file:

```
ant.project.setProperty('env.foo', 'bar')
```

[Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html#N11922) mention few other ways (note, without project):

```
ant.buildDir = buildDir
ant.properties.buildDir = buildDir
ant.properties['buildDir'] = buildDir
ant.property(name: 'buildDir', location: buildDir)
```