# How to build nginx with openssl for x86 on ubuntu 15 x86_64 by gradle script

Tags: linux, nginx, gradle, openssl

I'm trying to build nginx 1.9.12 with openssl 1.0.2g.

nginx builds openssl by itself using ./config (script from openssl package).
Unfortunately ./config script detect OS architecture: ``` [ "$MACHINE" ] || MACHINE=``(uname -m) 2>/dev/null`` || MACHINE="unknown" ``` and based on this creates Makefile (for x86_64 in this case).

I provides `-m32` argument through nginx to openssl, but it's not enough.
I need to change\provides env. variable MACHINE which will equal x86.

It seems that gradle "environment" (in Exec task) does not work. Well it works for nginx, but argument is not passed to subprocess (./config).

So I have situation when linker fails because cannot link x86 objects with x86_64.

Is there a way to set env. variable MACHINE in gradle script?

Comment: http://superuser.com ?

Comment: @user3159253 - I think the controlling factor here is Michal is trying to configure and build the contraption, and I think that puts it squarely on Stack Overflow. Other questions, like runtime Nginx config, would be a question for another site.

Answer (score 0):

> I provides "-m32" argument through nginx to openssl, but it's not enough. I need to change\provides env. variable MACHINE which will equal x86.

You cannot simply add `-m32` and build the OpenSSL sources. You must allow OpenSSL to configure itself and write out the `<openssl/opensslconf.h>` file.

This:

```
[ "$MACHINE" ] || MACHINE=(uname -m) 2>/dev/null
```

means you can export `MACHINE` and OpenSSL should honor it at that line. You should probably set it to i686: `$ MACHINE=i686 ./config -m32`. How things work after that is a crap shoot, however :)

The crap shoot come in because setting `MACHINE` is usually done for a cross-compile. There's also a variable called `CROSS_COMPILE` that comes into play. Also see OpenSSL's [`Configure`](http://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/Configure) script.

Here's a couple of tests:

```
# On i686 machine
$ MACHINE=i686 ./config 
Operating system: i686-whatever-linux2

# On i686 machine
$ MACHINE=x86_64 ./config 
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2

# On x86_64 machine
$ MACHINE=i686 ./config 
Operating system: i686-whatever-linux2

# On x86_64 machine
$ MACHINE=x86_64 ./config 
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
```

---

> Is there a way to set env. variable MACHINE in gradle script?

Sorry, no idea. Nginx is aggravating enough. I'm not sure I'd add another level of indirection to make problems even harder to fix.

Maybe this will help: [Setting environment variables from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8788823).

---

OpenSSL has a `Configure` and it takes a `LIST` argument:

```
$ ./Configure LIST | grep linux
...
linux-aarch64
linux-alpha-gcc
linux-aout
...
linux-generic32
linux-generic64
...
```

I believe you want to Configure OpenSSL with `linux-generic32` or `linux-elf`. However, I don't believe you can use `linux-elf` because it will pickup the host's architecture.

I had a lot of problems with Nginx's build system in the past with respect to getting OpenSSL configured properly (especially when using the FIPS validated object module). I seem to recall I needed modify their build scripts to get what I needed. You may need to do the same.

---

Here's what I am seeing for a Fedora 23 i686 machine. Notice it uses the `i686-whatever-linux2` triplet that results in `linux-elf`.

```
$ cd openssl-master
$ ./config 
Operating system: i686-whatever-linux2
Configuring for linux-elf
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.0-pre5-dev (0x0x10100005L)
    no-crypto-mdebug [default]  OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG (skip dir)
    no-crypto-mdebug-backtrace [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG_BACKTRACE (skip dir)
    no-dynamic-engine [forced]  
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-egd          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EGD (skip dir)
    no-heartbeats   [default]  OPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS (skip dir)
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
    no-shared       [default] 
    no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE (skip dir)
    no-ssl3         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL3 (skip dir)
    no-ssl3-method  [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL3_METHOD (skip dir)
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
    no-weak-ssl-ciphers [default]  OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default] 
    no-zlib-dynamic [default] 
Configuring for linux-elf
CC            =gcc
CFLAG         =-Wall -O3 -pthread -DL_ENDIAN -fomit-frame-pointer  -Wa,--noexecstack
SHARED_CFLAG  =-fPIC
DEFINES       =DSO_DLFCN HAVE_DLFCN_H NDEBUG OPENSSL_THREADS OPENSSL_NO_DYNAMIC_ENGINE OPENSSL_PIC OPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS OPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 OPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT OPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m SHA1_ASM SHA256_ASM SHA512_ASM MD5_ASM RMD160_ASM AES_ASM VPAES_ASM WHIRLPOOL_ASM GHASH_ASM ECP_NISTZ256_ASM POLY1305_ASM
LFLAG         =
PLIB_LFLAG    =
EX_LIBS       =-ldl 
APPS_OBJ      =
CPUID_OBJ     =x86cpuid.o
UPLINK_OBJ    =
BN_ASM        =bn-586.o co-586.o x86-mont.o x86-gf2m.o
EC_ASM        =ecp_nistz256.o ecp_nistz256-x86.o
DES_ENC       =des-586.o crypt586.o
AES_ENC       =aes-586.o vpaes-x86.o aesni-x86.o
BF_ENC        =bf-586.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4-586.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5-586.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =md5-586.o
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =sha1-586.o sha256-586.o sha512-586.o
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=rmd-586.o
CMLL_ENC      =cmll-x86.o
MODES_OBJ     =ghash-x86.o
PADLOCK_OBJ   =e_padlock-x86.o
CHACHA_ENC    =chacha-x86.o
POLY1305_OBJ  =poly1305-x86.o
BLAKE2_OBJ    =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =/usr/bin/ranlib
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =/usr/bin/perl

THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode
BN_LLONG mode

Configured for linux-elf.
```

`linux-generic32` looks very similar to `i686-whatever-linux2` and `linux-elf`:

```
$ ./Configure linux-generic32
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.0-pre5-dev (0x0x10100005L)
    no-crypto-mdebug [default]  OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG (skip dir)
    no-crypto-mdebug-backtrace [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG_BACKTRACE (skip dir)
    no-dynamic-engine [forced]  
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-egd          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EGD (skip dir)
    no-heartbeats   [default]  OPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS (skip dir)
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
    no-shared       [default] 
    no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE (skip dir)
    no-ssl3         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL3 (skip dir)
    no-ssl3-method  [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL3_METHOD (skip dir)
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
    no-weak-ssl-ciphers [default]  OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default] 
    no-zlib-dynamic [default] 
Configuring for linux-generic32
CC            =gcc
CFLAG         =-Wall -O3 -pthread 
SHARED_CFLAG  =-fPIC
DEFINES       =DSO_DLFCN HAVE_DLFCN_H NDEBUG OPENSSL_THREADS OPENSSL_NO_DYNAMIC_ENGINE OPENSSL_PIC
LFLAG         =
PLIB_LFLAG    =
EX_LIBS       =-ldl 
APPS_OBJ      =
CPUID_OBJ     =mem_clr.o
UPLINK_OBJ    =
BN_ASM        =bn_asm.o
EC_ASM        =
DES_ENC       =des_enc.o fcrypt_b.o
AES_ENC       =aes_core.o aes_cbc.o
BF_ENC        =bf_enc.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4_enc.o rc4_skey.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5_enc.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=
CMLL_ENC      =camellia.o cmll_misc.o cmll_cbc.o
MODES_OBJ     =
PADLOCK_OBJ   =
CHACHA_ENC    =chacha_enc.o
POLY1305_OBJ  =
BLAKE2_OBJ    =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =/usr/bin/ranlib
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =/usr/bin/perl

THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode
BN_LLONG mode
RC4 uses unsigned char

Configured for linux-generic32.
```